# How to set text in Lable, from variable that is initialized in __init__?

Tags: python, kivy

This is my t.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Simple(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Simple, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # THIS IS SIMLE EXAMPLE, IN PRACTICE I AM READING VALUE FROM TEXT FILE
        self.sometext = 'Hello from Init.'

    def set_text(self):
        return self.sometext # error: 'Simple' object has no attribute 'sometext'
        #return "Hello World from Simple(BoxLayout)" # this is working 


class TApp(App): 
    def build(self):
        return Simple()


TApp().run()
```

My t.kv

```
<Simple>:
    Label:
        #text: 'Hello World' # THIS IS WORKING
        text: root.set_text()
```

So this is not working
What need to be done to get it working ?

I hope that it is posible...

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested this simple example, where you set `self.sometext` directly? The problem could be in the code where you retrieve a value from file.

Comment: Do not understand. Can you provide code sample please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a copy of my reply from the kivy mailing list:

> It looks like the kv language ends up calling `set_text` before
>   `__init__`,  which seems weird but does explain your problem.
>
> You could fix it in various ways, but I would do the whole thing using
>   a  kivy property to keep things simple. I made an example at 
>   https://gist.github.com/inclement/8268019 . Although the default is
>   set to  `''`, the kv lang can automatically detect that it's a property
>   and make a  binding so that when `__init__` changes it the text is
>   updated.

The linked example code is:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_string('''
<Simple>:
    Label:
        #text: 'Hello World' # THIS IS WORKING
        text: root.sometext
''')

class Simple(BoxLayout):
    sometext = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Simple, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.sometext = 'Hello from Init.'

class TApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Simple()


TApp().run()
```